# when an activity starts but when do we use onStart()

Tags: android, oncreate, onstart

I know we call `onCreate()` when an activity starts but when do we use `onStart()`?

Answer (score 3):

Theses are like a callback method which we have as the part of activity life cycle. All method call when they should as activity starts you just override few of them.

In android all function started with "on" are like a callbackback function proivded to you.

these a all function called as the part of lifecyle. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`onStart()` - Called just before the activity becomes visible to the user.
Followed by `onResume()` if the activity comes to the foreground, or `onStop()` if it becomes hidden.

This might help you clarify: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks